# Python LXML HTML Request Returning Split Element JSON Response

Tags: python, html, json, lxml, screen-scraping

I am trying to do a basic scrape using LXML and XPATH, but for some reason, the response is changing with subsequent runs. Why is this happening? I have spent days  modifying the XPATH with no solution. I would Google the problem, but I don't even know what this would be called. Appreciate any guidance.

## PY SCRIPT

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from time import sleep

def parser(asin):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/"+asin+"/ref=olp_f_used?ie=UTF8&f_collectible=true&f_usedAcceptable=true&f_usedGood=true&f_used=true&f_usedLikeNew=true&f_usedVeryGood=true"
    page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        try:
            doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
            RAW_OFFER_USED_CONDITION = doc.xpath('//span[@class="a-size-medium olpCondition a-text-bold"]//text()')
            OFFER_USED_CONDITION = RAW_OFFER_USED_CONDITION if RAW_OFFER_USED_CONDITION else None

            if page.status_code!=200:
                raise ValueError('captha')

            data = {
                    'OFFER_USED_CONDITION':OFFER_USED_CONDITION
                   }

            return data
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

def readcsv():
    AsinList = ['B00001SHNG']
    extracted_data = []
    for i in AsinList:
        asin = i
        print("Processing: "+asin)
        extracted_data.append(parser(asin))
        sleep(1)
    print(extracted_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    readcsv()
```

## RESPONSE 1

```
[{'OFFER_USED_CONDITION': ['\n\n       Used\n         - Acceptable\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Good\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Good\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Good\n       ', '\n\n       Collectible\n         - Acceptable\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Very Good\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Good\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Very Good\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Like New\n       ', '\n\n       Used\n         - Very Good\n       ']}]
```

## RESPONSE 2

```
[{'OFFER_USED_CONDITION': ['\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Acceptable\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Good\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Good\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Good\n', '\n', '\n    Collectible\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Acceptable\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Very Good\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Good\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Very Good\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Like New\n', '\n', '\n    Used\n    \n\n\n\n-\n', '\n    Very Good\n', '\n']}]
```

Comment: Maby Amazon is JavaScript based site

Comment: Yes, I assume it does, but I am successfully pulling prices and other product information. Would Javascript cause this issue though?

Comment: I would assume the they have changed their page rendering logic. Unless you are getting randomly response 1 or response 2. Also changes take some time to apply all over the servers.

Comment: @Biswanath it is random. Sometimes it'll come in correctly, others it will be Response 2. There is no consistency and it is only happening with this XPATH.

Comment: It must be on my end, I modified the script to use Scraper API for the request and it's now correct every single time. Still would like to know why...